# Getting past Auth1.0a of Twitter API using fetch in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, fetch-api

I'm trying to change my banner on Twitter using 'node-fetch' library, but I can't get past Authentication 1.0a which is needed to post something on Twitter. My last try was using `headers.Authorization = "OAuth ACCESS_TOKEN ACCESS_SECRET"` but it was a failure. So my question is, what is the correct way of using Auth1.0a in 'node-fetch'?

The `ACCESS_TOKEN` and `ACCESS_SECRET` in the code are not mine, but randomly typed in.

```
fetch(`https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/update_profile_banner.json`, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: {
        banner: b64,
    },
    headers: {
        Authorization: "OAuth 2123123415-kbZfcGdHqKxTLlazrgQtzhzhKgHhjgtrLZq6789gui th67jz27z7gh3xhr5ghhgjj1gjHNMthtzuthfnOp3hJwhS5frx"
    }
}).then(results => results.json()).then(data => console.log(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample Authorization header from their [docs](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-1-0a/authorizing-a-request):
`Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="xvz1evFS4wEEPTGEFPHBog", oauth_nonce="kYjzVBB8Y0ZFabxSWbWovY3uYSQ2pTgmZeNu2VS4cg",oauth_signature="tnnArxj06cWHq44gCs1OSKk%2FjLY%3D", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1318622958", oauth_token="370773112-GmHxMAgYyLbNEtIKZeRNFsMKPR9EyMZeS9weJAEb", oauth_version="1.0"`

As you can see there are many more fields to consider, I suggest you read the docs carefully.
The placement of your Auth header is correct.